# Adding objects to Firebase Database

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add objects to a Firebase database and to retrieve the name and value from two text boxes.

```
<label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Beer Name</span>
          <input type="text" id='nomeBirra'>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Review</span>
          <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Enter review" id="Recensione"></textarea>
        </label>
```

This retrieves the two text areas:

```
var nameBirra=document.getElementById("nomeBirra")
var valueBirra=document.getElementById("Recensione")
```

This is the piece of code that adds a new object to database

```
rootRef.child("databaseBirre").set({
name: nameBirra,
value:  valueBirra
})
```

The problem is that it works, but the two parameters appear empty in the database. How can I retrieve the values inside the text boxes? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firebase syntax is right, which is why it's appearing in the database - it's the other bit that is wrong. There are a few things that could be wrong but it's hard to say without seeing the context (e.g. are those getElementByIds wrapped in a function etc?) but the most obvious one is that you need to get the VALUE of the input box, not the box itself. So, first thing to try:

```
var nameBirra=document.getElementById("nomeBirra").value
```

etc

Comment: it works!
and yeah, the other error was that the two getelementsbyid were inside the controller, but not the function which sends the data.